# Extension of Poisson Parameter for Different Temporal Interval

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Suppose $Y$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $ \lambda $ that explains a temporal Poisson process over an interval of 30 seconds.

Now, it stands to reason that for an interval of 60 seconds, the rate parameter ($\lambda$) of the new distribution would be $2\lambda$.

[Let’s generate a 95% confidence interval (Garwood)](https://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/calculator.aspx?id=86) for both of these. When $ Y = 10 $ the CI is $ (4.80,18.40) $. When $ Y = 20 $ the CI is $ (12.22, 30.89) $.

Why is the second CI not double the first CI ($(9.60,37.20)$)?

Comment: Is $\lambda$ parameter or the value of observed random variable?

Comment: Given that we’ve performed only one experiment, $\lambda$ is both the Poisson rate parameter and the value of the observed variable.

Comment: Cannot be both. See the answer, $Y$ is observed number, $\lambda$ is parameter.

Comment: Try to read some basic statistical text books.

Comment: @user158565 you are fundamentally right, but here is what I think: Given that we have one experiment, our estimation for the rate parameter also happens to be the value of the observed variable. In other words, in this specific instance: $Y=\lambda$. This is not true for most Poisson experiments, where $\lambda$ would be the rate parameter. If I am still wrong, can you please explain?

Comment: Parameter and the estimate of the parameter are two totally different concepts. In your case, "$Y$ is the parameter" is wrong; "Y is the estimate of that parameter" is correct.

Comment: @user158565 thank you very much. I updated the question. Is the update proper?

Comment: I edited your question. If you say $\lambda = 10$, it means you already know the parameter, then do not need to guess/estimate.

Comment: Thank you very much @user158565

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y_1$ be the number of events in the first 30 seconds and $Y_2$ be the number of events in the next 30 seconds.

The interval isn't twice as wide because the distribution of $Y_1+Y_2$ isn't twice as wide as that for $Y_1$.

Note that waiting twice as long means you're observing two 30 second intervals and that (with a Poisson process) the events in those two disjoint intervals are independent.

Consider, for example, that $\text{Var}(Y_1+Y_2) = \text{Var}(Y_1) + \text{Var}(Y_2) = 2\lambda$, so $\text{sd}(Y_1+Y_2)=\sqrt{2}\,\text{sd}(Y_1)$.

[If you observed for 30 seconds and doubled the resulting count, that would have standard deviation twice that of the count from observing for 30 seconds. But two independent counts don't do that.]

Now even though the standard deviation increases by a multiple of $\sqrt 2$ (and in proportion to $\sqrt{t}$ more generally) the corresponding interval won't be quite $\sqrt{2}$ as wide either because the shape changes as well -- among other things the skewness is less pronounced.